# Primefaces nested Datatable RowEdit adding the same sell to parrent Datatable(UI only) tree

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable, roweditor, rowexpansion

Currently I am facing a datatable rendering issue.

I have a datatable with order details with row expansion. When I click on the expansion arrow it shows line item details in another datatable.
Also have a + button to add new order and one more button inside line item table to add more line items.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

When I click on row edit under the line item table (This is under row expansion) the row open it edit mode,but when I click on tick icon the same lineitem updated but one duplicate lineitem is shown with parent table(order) and existing parrent linetable disappeard.But when I refresh the page this duplicate row is removed.

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

After clicking the arrow it appears like this

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

Is this a know issue in primefaces 11.Is the row expansion is only for view purpose?

***XHTML***

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces Test</title>
    <h:outputScript name="test.js"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="test.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h1>#{testView.string}</h1>
    <h:form id="form">


        <div class="card">
            <h5>Row Editing</h5>
            <p:dataTable id="order" var="order" value="#{mainBean.orderVOs}"
                         editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px" styleClass="myclass"
                         rowKey="#{order.orderNo}" rowIndexVar="orderIndex" showGridlines="true">


                <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{mainBean.onRowEdit(order)}"
                        update=":form:order"/>
                <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                        listener="#{mainBean.onRowCancel(order)}" update=":form:order"/>

                <p:column style="width:2rem">
                    <p:rowToggler/>
                </p:column>


                <p:column style="width:6rem">

                    <f:facet name="header">

                        <p:commandButton value="+"
                                         styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-plus"
                                         actionListener="#{mainBean.addOrder()}" update="order"
                                         oncomplete="editLastDatatableRow();"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:rowEditor editTitle="Edit Row" cancelTitle="Cancel Edit"
                                 saveTitle="Save Row"/>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="OrderNo">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{order.orderNo}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{order.orderNo}"
                                         style="width:100%"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="AddressLine1">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{order.addressLine1}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{order.addressLine1}" style="width:100%"
                                         label="Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="GrandTotal">
                    <p:cellEditor>
                        <f:facet name="output">
                            <h:outputText value="#{order.totalAmt}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="input">
                            <p:inputText value="#{order.totalAmt}" style="width:100%"
                                         label="Name"/>
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:cellEditor>
                </p:column>


                <p:rowExpansion>

                    <div class="card">
                        <h5>Row Editing</h5>
                        <p:dataTable id="lineItem" var="line" value="#{order.lineItems}"
                                     editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px"
                                     rowKey="#{ineItem.productDescription}" rowIndexVar="lineIndex"
                                     styleClass="myClass${orderIndex}" size="small" showGridlines="true">
                            <p:ajax event="rowEdit"
                                    listener="#{mainBean.onRowEditLine(order,line)}"
                                    update="form:order:${orderIndex}:lineItem form:order"/>
                            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel"
                                    listener="#{mainBean.onRowCancelLine(order,line)}"
                                    update="form:order:${orderIndex}:lineItem"/>

                            <p:column style="width:6rem">

                                <f:facet name="header">

                                    <p:commandButton value="+"
                                                     styleClass="rounded-button ui-button-plus"
                                                     actionListener="#{mainBean.addLine(order)}"
                                                     update="form:order:${orderIndex}:lineItem"
                                                     oncomplete="editLastDatatableRowLine(${orderIndex});"/>
                                </f:facet>
                                <p:rowEditor editTitle="Edit Row" cancelTitle="Cancel Edit"
                                             saveTitle="Save Row"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="productDescription">
                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{line.productDescription}"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <p:inputText id="modelInput"
                                                     value="#{line.productDescription}" style="width:100%"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="quantity">
                                <p:cellEditor>
                                    <f:facet name="output">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{line.quantity}"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                    <f:facet name="input">
                                        <p:inputText value="#{line.quantity}" style="width:100%"
                                                     label="Name"/>
                                    </f:facet>
                                </p:cellEditor>
                            </p:column>


                        </p:dataTable>
                    </div>


                </p:rowExpansion>

            </p:dataTable>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function editLastDatatableRow() {

                jQuery('.myclass .ui-datatable-data tr').first().find(
                        'span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).click()
                });
            }
            
            function editLastDatatableRowLine(index) {

                jQuery('.myClass'+index+" "+ '.ui-datatable-data tr').first().find(
                        'span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function() {
                    jQuery(this).click()
                });
            }
            
            

        </script>
    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

***Bean***

```
package org.primefaces.test;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class MainBean implements Serializable {

    /**
     *
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7536893702695858952L;
    List<OrderVO> orderVOs;
    private List<LineVO> lineItems;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        orderVOs = new ArrayList<OrderVO>();
        lineItems = new ArrayList<LineVO>();
        LineVO l1 = new LineVO("desc1", "d", "s", "s", "d");
        lineItems.add(l1);
        OrderVO orderVO = new OrderVO();
        orderVO.setOrderNo("10000");
        orderVO.setAddressLine1("address1");
        orderVO.setLineItems(lineItems);
        orderVOs.add(orderVO);

    }

    public List<LineVO> getLineItems() {
        return lineItems;
    }

    public void setLineItems(List<LineVO> lineItems) {
        this.lineItems = lineItems;
    }

    public List<OrderVO> getOrderVOs() {
        return orderVOs;
    }

    public void setOrderVOs(List<OrderVO> orderVOs) {
        this.orderVOs = orderVOs;
    }

    public void onRowEdit(OrderVO orderVO) {

    }

    public void onRowCancel(OrderVO orderVO, LineVO lineVO) {

    }

    public void onRowEditLine(OrderVO orderVO, LineVO lineVO) {

    }

    public void onRowCancelLine(OrderVO orderVO, LineVO lineVO) {

    }

    public void addOrder() {
        OrderVO orderVO = new OrderVO();
        orderVOs.add(0, orderVO);

    }

    public void addLine(OrderVO orderVO) {
        LineVO lineVO = new LineVO("dd", "jjj", "kk", "ooo", "iiiii");
        if (orderVO.getLineItems() == null) {
            orderVO.setLineItems(new ArrayList<LineVO>());
        }

        orderVO.getLineItems().add(0, lineVO);

    }

}
```

Reproucable code present here .github.com/akhiltm20/primefaces-rowExpansion_innerTableIssue
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaiIw.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsK5J.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYrcM.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IvTZ.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwA81.png

Comment: Please add a [mcve], see https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces-test

Comment: @JasperdeVries I have checkout the git sample and modified with sample code,but dont know how to upload the zip

Comment: If you forked the repo, you could push your branch to GitHub

Comment: @JasperdeVries code committed .https://github.com/akhiltm20/primefaces-rowExpansion_innerTableIssue

Comment: @JasperdeVries Could you please confirm the issue is a bug or not?